# Is it OK to ask if a recorded sound was emitted by a bat?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

*Note: the question is [now posted](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/39015/18925) on Biology.SE.*

For fun, I tried to record sounds emitted by bats in an area where bats were flying all around.

By doing a few manipulations with the audio record (like lowering the frequency to actually be able to “hear” what was originally ultrasound), I can clearly hear a sound emitted by an animal. On the other hand, a few resources I've found on the internet could indicate that the frequency of the sounds emitted by bats is much higher than the sound I actually recorded.

My question would be to know if those are actually bats, and if not, what other animal could emit those sounds.

If I:

1. Post the link to the audio,
2. Explain what exact post-processing operations were made to transform the original into the final audio,
3. Post the screenshots showing the actual pattern of the sound (several repeated pulses),
4. Link to the actual websites which give a hint that the frequency I should expect is much higher than what I actually get,
5. Indicate the geographical location of the recording and give information about the time of the night the recording took place,

would my question be on-topic here?

If the question would be off-topic, is there a more appropriate SE site? [Pets.SE](https://pets.stackexchange.com/) makes “livestock, wildlife, and pests in and around your home” off-topic; [Outdoors.SE](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) seems a very strange place for such question.

Is there anything else I should do to improve the chances for the question to be answered?

Comment: Personally, I think it should be on-topic for BioSE, since it is very similar to species identification questions, and these are considered on-topic here. Your question could also be framed in terms of methods to perform species inventories (e.g. estimating biodiversity), which is also on-topic for the site.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question. Go for it.